# Links not working bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

so I have a couple of divs which I'm showing and hiding using jquery's `.hide` and `.show`, and for some reason the `<a>` links inside those divs don't work (they're not clickable and right-clicking doesn't list the option to open either).
   I tried `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, with no results.
   Here is the divs in question and the script interacting with them:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#2017").click(function(e) {
            $("#pastExpos").show();
            $(".dinamicY").hide();
            $("#17").show();
        });
        $("#2016").click(function(e) {
            $("#pastExpos").show();
            $(".dinamicY").hide();
            $("#16").show();
        });
        $("#2015").click(function(e) {
            $("#pastExpos").show();
            $(".dinamicY").hide();
            $("#15").show();
        });
        $("#2014").click(function(e) {
            $("#pastExpos").show();
            $(".dinamicY").hide();
            $("#14").show();
        });
        $("#2013").click(function(e) {
            $("#pastExpos").show();
            $(".dinamicY").hide();
            $("#13").show();
        });
    });     
</script>
```

```html
<div class="dinamicC" id="contentP">
                <div class="col-md-1" id="years">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="2017"><a href="#">2017</a></li>
                        <li id="2016"><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                        <li id="2015"><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                        <li id="2014"><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
  
                <div class="col-md-6" id="pastExpos">
                    <div class="dinamicY" id="17">
                        <h3><a src="Replica.html">Miguel Palma</a></h3>
                        <p>Réplica</p>
                        <b>28 de Abril a 3 de Junho</b>
                        <br>
                        <h3><a src="Dialogo.html">Juan Escauriaza</a></h3>
                        <p>um diálogo com a cidade</p>
                        <b>5 de Maio a 28 de Maio</b>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dinamicY" id="16">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <a src="02016.html">André Sier</a>
                            <p>02016.41312785388128</p>
                            <b>20 de Maio a 4 de Junho de 2016</b>
                            <br>
                            <h3><a src="Les_Voyeurs.html">Mário Rita</a></h3>
                            <p>Les Voyeurs</p>
                            <b>4 a 12 de Maio de 2016</b>
                            <br>
                            <h3><a src="Nishikigoi.html">Yves Callewaert</a></h3>
                            <p>Nishikigoi</p>
                            <b>19 de Fevereiro a 18 de Março</b>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="dinamicY" id="15">
                            <h3><a src="Paisagens.html">Paisagens Inesperadas</a></h3>
                            <p>Nuno Cera, Mariana Marote, Miguel Palma e outros</p>
                            <p>Curadoria de Adelaide Ginga</p>
                            <b>30 de Outubro a 13 de Dezembro de 2015</b>
                            <br>
                            <h3><a src="Voltar.html">Diogo Maia</a></h3>
                            <p>Voltar</p>
                            <b>14 de Março a 11 de Abril de 2015</b>
                            <br>
                            <h3><a src="Une_image.html">Pires Vieira</a></h3>
                            <p>Une image peut en cacher une autre</p>
                            <b>13 de Fevereiro a 28 de Março de 2015</b>
                            <br>
                            <h3><a src="mario.html">3x3=9</a></h3>
                            <p>De passagem pelo Cais do Sodré</p>
                            <b>6 de Janeiro a 5 de Março de 2015</b>
                            <br>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="dinamicY" id="14">
                            <h3><a src="ephemeros.html">Maria Costa</a></h3>
                            <p>Ephemerós</p>
                            <b>6 de Novembro a 20 de Dezembro de 2014</b>
                            <br>
                    </div>   
                </div>
```

Help? 
  Thank you

Comment: It might help if you posted *SOME* code.

Comment: try to reproduce the bug here...........

Comment: Added. Sorry, I was unsure on how it would help given that it is a simple scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `href` not `src` in your links:

```
<a href="page.html">
```